# Permission issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

From facebook graph api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I generated a token, without asking any permission. By view the profile I actually see all education, work history, this is not right!

```
token permission:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1,
      "type": "permissions"
    }
  ]
}
```

Did another test
1. remove my test app from facebook
2. connected to test app from my website without ask any permission
3. get the token 
4. make graph api call /me
5. get a lot information I didn't ask, e.g. education, work history, email, hometown...

test the token permission, it only show

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1,
      "type": "permissions"
    }
  ]
}
```

any idea?

Comment: This may sounds obvious, but have you chosen the right App from the drop down menu?

Comment: I chose my test app in graph api explorer, not the default app. From my second test I got an access token by going through the oauth2 server flow and its nothing to do with graph api explorer, using the token making profile api call I'm still getting the extra profile information.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you have unrestricted privacy settings, while this shouldn't affect how apps see your data but it *may* be the problem

Comment: @ifaour, you are right. All my profile info set to public in privacy settings, that's why graph API can access all my data without ask a single permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe calling `https://graph.facebook.com/user_id_OR_username` would not only retrieve basic information but all your info set to public in the privacy settings.

*P.S.: read question comments.*